# Exception tracking solutions

Tags: exception, tracking, bug-tracking, saas

is there any alternatives to AirBrake and Exceptional.io ? I've tried both, I think they are more oriented to Ruby/Rails projects. What I'm looking for is a SaaS solution that tracks Java exceptions.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is: [Coalmine](https://getcoalmine.com) It's mavenized, extremely easy to use, and reliable. The [Java connector](https://github.com/coalmine/coalmine_java) is officially supported by the company.

I am a co-founder of Coalmine ;) Let me know if you have any specific questions on how to get started.